HighCharts does not render (/create elements) - how to debug / check for failure
We're currently changing some pages to a new kind of layout, but still using the same layout page we've always used, just a different kind of topmenu style is used (added using a collection to the view - if it exist, show that topmenu - if it doesn't show the old)
The chart has always worked before - it's not new. In other pages (also with the new "topmenu") other highcharts still work, but in one particular page the chart does not draw or to be more specific, it does not create the highcharts elements within the container - also: There is no error message, no console log, but also no chart - just nothing.
If I use the script to create the chart and paste it into a JSFiddle from a Highchart demo is works (as it did) - but not on this page.
And I have no clue as where to start to debug this particular page. If I git-revert to the old page (same Razor component to create the chart btw) all works as intended. Change to the new; nothing : the only thing changed is a partial with a collection that's added to the view - and in other views there is no problem whatsoever.
EDIT #1 - this is the JsFiddle for the exact script (except for names and container ID --> also container ID has not changed) : https://jsfiddle.net/5qxkwtza/
EDIT #2 - the container DIV is not hidden

The first step to debug this problem would be by finding if the JS code appears on the page. Secondly, could you please provide more information regarding your setup? Are you using the .NET Highcharts wrapper or are you using the standard JS library?

@jedrzejruta - I added a Fiddle with the exact code which is rendered on the page (but does not render a chart) - We're not using a wrapper, just the standard JS lib

@jedrzejruta - in the JsFiddle and on the old page it does render a chart - the container div is also still there (otherwise I would have expected a HighChart 13 error)

You can also check if Highcharts library is correctly imported into the web page, e.g. by logging the Highcharts object to the console. The config of the chart is okay, so you can start by checking if it is actually available on the website or if it doesn't initialize too early, before the DOM is fully loaded.

@jedrzejruta the console.log does contain the Highcharts object, the DOM is loaded, but you gave me a suggestion. I did a console.log on the container, I set a timeout on docReady (few seconds) and again did a console.log on the container. The container initially was normal, after a few seconds the height and width were 0 + collapse class was added. Chart container name interfered with the plugin we use to display the new topmenu. It's fixed, so if you add an answer with your suggestions I will mark it as solved.

As a first step, you can make sure that the Highcharts library is correctly imported and loaded on the web page by e.g. doing a console.log(Highcharts).
Secondly, you can check if the container for the chart is visible and if the chart doesn't get initialized too early, before the DOM structure is fully loaded.
